# Cursor postion comes to start of the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a small problem. In my activity I have an edittext and a button.

Clicking on the button I am changing the inputtype of the edittext.

Now when I click button the input type changes but the cursor goes to the begining of the text in the edittext.

How can I retain the same position of the cursor or can I bring the cursor to the end of the text?

I tried `setSelection(edittextobj.getText().length())` but doesnot work how can I achive this....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is correct, as far as it goes.  The problem must lie elsewhere.  Try ensuring your string is the correct string, and that you're setting everything in the correct order.

Comment: Additional question: What do you mean by "setting everything in the correct order" ? What would be the correct order? This one: Change input type, then set the new string on the Edittext ? Would be great, if the OP or someone else could briefly explain what makes this the correct answer. I'd like to avoid using the setSelection command, because it should not be required for a simple Edittext to work properly.

Comment: What I mean by the correct order is just make sure you're not doing anything crazy like setting the text after you set the selection or something like that.  The code in the question is correct, but it doesn't show the entirety of the problem

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure, the complete code is:

```
edittextobj.setSelection(edittextobj.getText().length());
```